# Access file in WebContent folder from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, apache-fop

I'm trying to generate a PDF document using FOP. The pdf generation code is kept in a servlet and the xsl is in a specific folder in the WebContent folder.

How can I access this xsl file by giving a relative path? It works only if I give the complete path in the File object.

I need to generate the xml content dynamically. How can I give this dynamically generated xml as the source instead of a File object?

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get the path you can just do:

```
String path = s.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/somedir/hdfeeh");
```

`s` is the class that implements `HTTPServlet`.You can also use `this.getServletContext()` if its your servlet class.

Then pass this as a parameter.

As far as using dynamically generated XML, the library you're using should support using an input stream, write your XML, convert it to a byte array, then wrap it in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and use this.

Comment: Don't quite get it. I don't know what is `s`?

Comment: @newbie `s` is an object that implements [`ServletConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html). `HttpServlet` extends a class that implements `ServletConfig`. This means that if your class extends `HttpServlet`, you can do `this.getServletContext()`.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. if I check file exists with such path, it will return false. have a look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598562/unable-to-access-file-in-web-inf-folder-from-servlet

Answer (score 6):

For a direct and independent container implementation, you can access the resourcewith the following method getResource() inside your servlet:

/*start servlet*/

```
public InputStream getResource(String resourcePath) {
  ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
  InputStream openStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream( resourcePath );
  return openStream;
}

public void testConsume() {
  String path = "WEB-INF/teste.log";
  InputStream openStream = getResource( path );

  int c = -1;
  byte[] bb = new byte[1024];
  while ( -1 != ( c = openStream.read( bb ) ) ) {
    /* consume stream */
  }
  openStream.close();
}
```

/*end servlet*/

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to load the resource into stream.

I get the exception java.net.MalformedURLException

I printed servletContext and its shown as com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.facade.ServletContextFacade@36c29971

Any ideas?

Comment: After using servletContext.getRealPath(filePath); its working fine :)

Comment: Here, the code work fine.

I'm using Tomcat 6.*.

Now I see that you are using IBM platform. Maybe, that's the difference between results.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following method to read the file under web content

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/json/sampleJson.json")));
```

Now all the file content is available in the reader object.