# Filedatasource path not coming dynamically

Tags: java, email

Hi I have the following code:

```
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress("krao346789@gmail.com");
    msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

    InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[sendTo.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < sendTo.length; i++) {
    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(sendTo[i]);
    }
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

    // Setting the Subject and Content Type
    msg.setSubject(emailSubjectTxt);
    /*Image part*/

    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");  

    // first part  (the html)  
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
    String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";  
    messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");  

    // add it  
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

    // second part (the image)  
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  
    String contextPath=request.getContextPath();
    System.out.println("contextpath"+contextPath);
    File contextDir = new File(contextPath);  
    System.out.println("contextDir"+contextDir);
    File emailImage = new File(contextDir, "/images/sample.jpeg"); 
    System.out.println("emailImage"+emailImage);

    DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(emailImage);  
    //System.out.println("fds"+fds.getName());
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));  
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");  

    // add it  
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);  

    // put everything together  
    msg.setContent(multipart);  
    Transport.send(msg);
}
```

It works fine if I use

```
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("C:\\images\\sample.jpeg");
```

instead of

```
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(emailImage);
```

But I want to access image from `WebContent->images`.
I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I run this.

Comment: Please post stack trace to be able to tell where the NullPointerException is.

Also you should do a check with `File.exists()` to see if the file does really exist where you think it is..

Comment: If you are using servlets to call that image then try this one
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479036/access-file-in-webcontent-folder-from-a-servlet

Comment: Which web application API is used? `Servlet JSP` or `JSF`.....

Comment: @Josephkingstonleo Mariamicheal- tried that...showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use in web application. First, you have to upload your attachment file to server as `InputStream` and then create attachment file by using this `InputStream`.

Comment: I dont wnat to create attachment. I want the image to go in the mail. Eg company logo

Comment: whatever it is, you have to upload `Image` to server side firstly.

Comment: @CycDemo-Its already there in server side...its in WebContent->images

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Use **getRealPath()**;
 Its working fine now.

File contextDir = new File(request.getRealPath("/images/sample.jpeg"));
 DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(contextDir);

Answer (score 0):

If `images/sample.jpeg` is from your resources folder then try this :

```
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(getFileHandle("images/sample.jpeg"));

public static File getFileHandle(String fileName){
       return new File(YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());
}
```

in case of non static reference:

```
return new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());
```