# Unable to access file in WEB-INF folder from servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I ran into a problem with accessing files within WebContent folder (in this case I need to access WEB-INF folder)

This is where I try to access WEB-INF folder.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    String dbPath = "/WEB-INF/musicDb.db";
    String xmlPath = "/WEB-INF/musicDb.xml";
    ServletContext context = null;
    context = getServletContext();  
    String test = context.getRealPath(xmlPath);

    File f = new File(test);
    if (f.exists()) {

    }
}
```

I have musicDb.xml ready in WEB-INF folder, however, by debugging, I always get this path instead

```
{my local project path}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/9321A1/WEB-INF/musicDb.xml
```

[image]

I suspect it has something to do with WebContent folder not being included in build process. This might be wrong.

Pretty much every tutorial/suggestion/article I've found so far point me to this approach using

> getServletContext().getRealPath()

which doesn't seem to work in my case

Any help would be appreciated.

Thang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you move the file to /WEB-INF/classes or package it in a jar and place that jar in WEB-INF/lib.  The load the file as a resource using any one of the getResourceAsSteam methods

See here: [Best practices to store and access resource files in java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005749/best-practices-to-store-and-access-resource-files-in-java-web-application) and the correct answer here: [Reading Web Application Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175128/reading-web-application-resources)

Comment: but why would moving a file into a sub-folder make any difference? btw, I tried changing the path to /WEB-INF/ and check if file exists, it return true. (if that helps the case in any ways)

Comment: Ok, apparently, it does make a difference. I moved it into WEB-INF/lib folder and it works perfectly. I still wanna know why though

Comment: I don't remember for sure but the I think the servlet or jsp specification says that files inside WEB-INF are not visible/accessible to the web app